# How to do conditional operations in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

```
test.columns
Out[8]: 
Index(['YearDeci', 'Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Seconds', 'Lat',
       'Lon', 'Depth', 'Magnitude', 'Mag_Type', 'Author', 'DepFIX', 'Mag',
       'MagType', 'Status'],
      dtype='object')

Magnitude  Mag_Type  Author  
4.6        mb        NCS        
3.7        ML        ABC    
4.0        Mb        CDE   
3.5        MD        EFG    
3.9        M         HIJ    
   

test[['Mag','Status']]=''


test["Mag"],test["Status"]  = np.where((test["Mag_Type"]=='ML')&(test["Author"]=='ABC'),test["Magnitude"]*0.9237,test["Magnitude"]), np.where((test["Mag_Type"]=='ML') &(test["Author"]=='ABC'),True,pass)

test["Mag"],test["Status"]  = np.where((test["Mag_Type"]=='Mb')&(test["Author"]=='CDE'),test["Magnitude"]*0.523,test["Magnitude"]), np.where((test["Mag_Type"]=='Mb') &(test["Author"]=='CDE'),True,pass)
.
.
.
Multiple statements
```

also I am doing multiple conditions like this so I want to monitor the changes I made in a `Status` column to identify the rows which not belongs to any of my applied conditions.
But since `pass` is not allowed in `np.where`. Is there any alternate solution for this?

Comment: Use `False` instead of `pass`?

Comment: Since I have to insert independent conditions in several lines of code,`False` will rewrite previously executed rows too

Comment: maybe elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve with some clear examples